# WETH Deposit Function on a Forked Mainnet?

Tags: ethers.js

Code below works on goerli testnet, however it does not work on a forked ETH mainnet. The code sends 1 ETH to WETH contract, and vice versa. Could someone please help an example of interacting with real contracts on a forked network? In this case swapping 1 ETH to WETH? I am using Hardhat.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const qs = require('qs');
const { ethers, getNamedAccounts, BigNumber } = require("hardhat")
const { networkConfig, developmentChains, DECIMALS } = 
require("../helper-hardhat-config");



async function main() {
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    const provider = new 
    ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(networkConfig[chainId] 
   ["rpc_url"]);
    const accounts = await provider.listAccounts();
  // const signer = provider.getSigner(accounts[0]);

    const weth_abi = '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"src","type":"address"},{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"deposit","outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"guy","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"dst","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Deposit","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"src","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"wad","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Withdrawal","type":"event"}]'
    const weth_address = networkConfig[chainId]["weth_contract_adr"]
    var weth_contract = new ethers.Contract(weth_address, weth_abi, provider);

    let wallet = new ethers.Wallet(networkConfig[chainId]["private_key"], provider)
    const account = wallet.address
    const signed = weth_contract.connect(wallet);
    var balance = await signed.balanceOf(account);
    console.log(`balance before: ${balance}`);

   // await signed.deposit({value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1")})

    await signed.withdraw(ethers.utils.parseEther("1"));

}

main()
```

Here is the error I am getting when I try on forked mainnet...

```
Error: missing response (requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_accounts\",\"params\":[],\"id\":42,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", serverError={"errno":-111,"code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":8545}, url="http://localhost:8545", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.0)
```

Comment: does your wallet have ETH on mainnet?

Comment: If you're calling withdraw, make sure you have WETH to begin with. And secondly, are you using the correct config? As in, does your config contain the correct address for weth on goerli?

Comment: My vallet does not have ETH on mainnet. I am trying to use the private key for one of the test accoutns created by hardhat (forking mainnet with alchemy RPC URL). Yes I have a "helper" config file with the correct WETH contract address for goeri vs mainnet.

Comment: I got it to work, I didn't have the forked node running. Thank you all for your help!